# How to add a cover/thumbnail to PDFs generated by gofpdf?

Tags: go, pdf, pdf-generation

I am creating PDFs from (mainly) images using [`gofdpf`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf/v2#section-readme) to read on my eReader. Everything works great, however the PDFs don't have a thumbnail/cover. This makes it hard to see what I am reading when I go to e.g. the home screen of my eReader, since it just shows up as a blank page until I click on it and open the PDF. Is there a way to add a cover/thumbnail using [`gofdpf`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf/v2#section-readme)?

From https://www.reddit.com/r/kobo/comments/8k5b53/comment/dz50n9k/ I know that something like Calibre can do this, but that would be quite impractical for my use-case.

As for what I've already tried: Since there doesn't seem to be a thumbnail/cover function, I tried doing the following to no avail:

```golang
pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")
pdf.AddPage()
pdf.SetFont("Arial", "", 11)
pdf.Image(example.ImageFile("logo.png"), 10, 10, 30, 0, false, "", 0, "")
pdf.Text(50, 20, "logo.png")
```

I have since removed the `AddPage`, `SetFont` and `Text` since I don't need them for the PDF, and the above code doesn't add the thumbnail/cover.

Comment: My reader does show the first page, yes. I will try to change the page size to see if that helps. After some searching, I also found [kepubify](https://github.com/pgaskin/kepubify) which may be able to do what I want, but I will have to look into it.